# Single AWS lambda with bigger responsibility vs multiple lambda's with less responsibility

Tags: amazon-web-services, parallel-processing, aws-lambda

I'm currently working on an indexing component where it creates the indexes in different database tables (DynamoDB, ElasticSearch etc) based on client configurations.

There could be potentially 100+ clients who need different indexing records and system's TPS is 700. Currently I have 2 approaches,

1. Have a single lambda listening to SQS (where events are subscribed) and pulls the data from the source and build index records for each clients and put the indexes in DB in parallel.
2. Or, In above approach, execution time will be longer - as parallel computation is depending on total number of cores available. So, have a small lambda that duplicates the incoming events with small number of clients (let's say for 1 incoming message, this lambda will create 10 new messages with 10 client's name in it) and push it to another SQS. And another lambda subscribed to it will listen to these messages and build index records for each clients and put the indexes in DB in parallel.

So, both approaches have few shortcomings,

1. Execution time is higher but less lambda invocations. Higher memory & higher CPU.
2. Less execution time but more lambda invocations. Less memory and moderately high CPU.

So, I want to have a cost effective solutions where I can achieve indexing component's maximum fan-out for building indexes for multiple clients. Also, what's the maximum parallelization I can achieve per AWS lambda instance?

Comment: Your choice between those two approaches you've come up with has multiple aspects that, personally, I cannot give a direct answer. But for *maximum parallelization*, you can use the lambda metric [ConcurrentExecutions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/concurrent-executions.html#monitoring-concurrent-usage). **By default**, the limitation of your account is also the limit of function(s)

Comment: By parallelization, I mean multiple threads running within same AWS Lambda - as I have to create multiple index records for different clients.